# Parallel Bagging in supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, bagging, parallel-computing

How can we parallelize Bootstrap aggregation, *a.k.a* Bagging, *i.e.* train all classifiers at once?

Comment: Hi, welcome. What exactly is your question? Why would this not be possible? It's an [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually bagging is a parallel ensemble: each model is built independently.

So its parallizing is pretty straightforward. The training set is partioned equally across several available processors. Each processor executes the sequential algorithm on its local data until sufficient predictors have been constructed.